# System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse, webresponse

I'm trying to navigate some webpages but sometimes I receive "the operation has timed out" error.. sometimes it works days without any error..
After received the error, if I try to navigate from WebBrowser, it navigate without any problem, but if I want to navigate with webrequest again, I get this error again...

I have tryied to set ReadWriteTimeout and Timeout property from 2-3 minutes, up to infinite.. still without any luck :(

here is my code:

```
static void setHeaders(ref WebRequest reqPOST, string sUrl)
{
reqPOST = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
reqPOST.Method = "GET";
((HttpWebRequest)reqPOST).UserAgent = "dummie useragent";
((HttpWebRequest)reqPOST).Accept = "*/*";
((HttpWebRequest)reqPOST).KeepAlive = true;
((HttpWebRequest)reqPOST).Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
reqPOST.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
reqPOST.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
}

static void getResponse(ref WebRequest reqPOST, ref WebResponse result, ref StreamReader reader, ref string responseFromServer)
{
result = reqPOST.GetResponse();
if (result.Headers.Get("Content-Encoding") != null && result.Headers.Get("Content-Encoding").ToLower() == "gzip")
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(new GZipStream(result.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
else
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
setHeaders(ref reqPOST, "somewebsite");
getResponse(ref reqPOST, ref result, ref reader, ref responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
result.Close();
```

any ideas please ? thank you.

Comment: This is not the bug, but you should research what `ref` does. You seem to come from a C++ background.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add

```
reqPOST.Timeout = 1000000; // Increase timeout
```